# How to get rid of the File Access Security Warning for EXEs downloaded with Firefox 26+?

Tags: windows, firefox, download, alternate-data-stream

When downloading an executable file in Firefox (26) windows shows the "File Access - Security warning". Since I am not stupid and don't try to execute downloaded files I don't trust and clearly don't need to be asked again every time I download something I'd like to disable this annoying warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this bugzilla entry](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=909022), there is a new `about:config` option that controls this behavior. Setting `browser.download.saveZoneInformation` to `false` disables it.

Answer (score 3):

For when setting `browser.download.saveZoneInformation` to `false` doesn't seem to work, one can try applying the following `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Do not preserve zone information in file attachments
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Attachments]
"SaveZoneInformation"=dword:00000001
```

Verified to work on Firefox 31, *without* rebooting the system, and even *without* restarting Firefox.

For information on the `SaveZoneInformation` Group Policy registry setting, see https://support.microsoft.com/kb/883260.